# how to send mails with tables using javax api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to modify a code which sends mails.
The requirement is to insert a table into the mail. This can be done easily if the content type of mail is text/html. But the content type set is text/plain. Is there a way to send mails with table for this content type.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ASCII table, but it would probably not be very attractive.  Why don't you simply use HTML?

An ASCII table example:

```
:-----------------------------:
: Name                : Score :
:---------------------:-------:
: Jones, Jim          :   100 :
: Falwell, Jerry      :    98 :
: Bakker, Jim         :    75 :
:-----------------------------:
```

Comment: The same mail code is being use at many places so if i change it to html then others will be affected. Can you plz tell me how to create this ASCII table.

Comment: By ASCII table, I mean using special characters to make table borders.  I will edit my answer to show...